# Is there a motion to select the comment block under the cursor?

Tags: cursor-motions, object-motions

One thing that I often need to do is reformat a code comment with <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> or <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>. For example, I often want to convert something like this:

```c
// Lorem ipsum 
// dolor
// sir 
// amet
int foo(int x) {
    return 17;
}
```

into this:

```c
// Lorem ipsum dolor sir amet
int foo(int x) {
    return 17;
}
```

Is there a vim motion I can use to select the entire comment block under the cursor? I tried using <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>}</kbd> and <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>but they also reformat the code under the comment, which is too much.

```c
// Lorem ipsum dolor sir amet
int foo(int x) { return 17; }
```

So far the best I could think is manually counting lines, using something like  <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>. But there ought to be a better way...

Comment: Unfortunately no, there isn't

Comment: It's not completely reliable, but if your Vim binary includes the patch [8.2.0915](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.0915), try this mapping: `ono <silent> ix :exe search('.$', 'W', 0, 0, {-> synstack(line('.'), col('.'))->map('synIDattr(v:val, "name")')->match('\ccomment') != -1}) ? 'norm! k' : ''<cr>`

Comment: @user938271: Could you please write that as an answer instead of as a comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using plug-ins is acceptable to you, then the [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) plug-in can help you.

It defines a [`gc` text object](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary/blob/f8238d70f873969fb41bf6a6b07ca63a4c0b82b1/doc/commentary.txt#L22) to select a comment, which you can use in operator pending mode. Use `gqgc` anywhere in the comment block to format the comment.

Note that if you are using C or C++ you may need to tell Vim to use `//` comments instead of `/**/` comments. You can define either the [`'commentstring'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27commentstring%27) option or alternatively the `b:commentary_format` buffer variable.

```
set commentstring=//%s
```